# Azure Service Bus, sending messages to topics using Python SDK

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics, azure-python-sdk

I have this snippet in a code that is running on a Function App:

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string('<conn_string>')
sender = client.get_topic_sender('<topic>')
sender.send_messages(ServiceBusMessage('<message>', subject='<subject>'))
```

Each time I try to send a message after the function is idle for a few minutes, the function seems to take much longer. I'm not very familiar with the mechanism of how this works, but it seems that the client or topic sender is reconnecting.

How can I keep this sender alive so that it won't take such a long time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: A message may be scheduled for delayed delivery using the `ServiceBusSender.schedule_messages()` method, or by specifying `ServiceBusMessage.scheduled_enqueue_time_utc` before calling `ServiceBusSender.send_messages()`
> The code below uses the Azure Service Bus client library for Python to send messages to Azure Service Bus topics [reference](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-servicebus/latest/index.html#send-messages-to-a-queue).

- The function is idle for a few minutes one possible [solution](https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/issues/135) is to set `sender.renew_sender()` every 10 minutes will ensure a continuous [connection](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus#send-messages-to-a-queue).

```py
service_bus_client.renew_sender()
                time.sleep(600)
```

- `MyServiceBusClient` class that connects to Azure Service Bus using a connection string and sends a message to a topic.
- The `send_message_to_topic()` function sends a message to the topic using the `sender` object.
- Create an Azure Service Bus and copy the Connection [String](https://i.imgur.com/AKnQ96A.png).Code reference from [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions?tabs=passwordless). For best implementation refer of Azure service Bus refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2).

**Code with `send_messages()`:**

```py
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

class MyServiceBusClient:
    def __init__(self, conn_str, topic_name):
        self.conn_str = conn_str
        self.topic_name = topic_name
        self.client = None
        self.sender = None

    def connect(self):
        if not self.client:
            self.client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(self.conn_str)
            self.sender = self.client.get_topic_sender(self.topic_name)

    def is_connected(self):
        return self.client is not None

    def send_message(self, message_body, subject=None):
        if not self.is_connected():
            raise Exception("Not connected to Azure Service Bus. Call connect() before sending messages.")

        sender = self.sender
        sender.send_messages(ServiceBusMessage(message_body, subject=subject))

    def close(self):
        if self.client:
            self.client.close()

def send_message_to_topic():
    # Initialize your Service Bus client
    service_bus_client = MyServiceBusClient('AzureServiceBusConn_String', 'AzureServiceBusTopic')

    try:
        # Connect to Azure Service Bus
        service_bus_client.connect()

        # Check if connected
        if service_bus_client.is_connected():
            # Send messages using the persistent sender
            service_bus_client.send_message('YourMessageBody', subject='YourSubject')
            print("Message sent successfully.")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect to Azure Service Bus.")

    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"An error occurred: {ex}")

    finally:
        # Close the client when done
        service_bus_client.close()

# Call the function to send a message to the topic
send_message_to_topic()
```

**Output:**
[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

- For more detail on [scheduling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-expiration) and schedule cancellation please see a sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/azure-servicebus_7.11.3/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/schedule_messages_and_cancellation.py).

[image]

**Scheduler  a timer to execute the [function](https://i.imgur.com/Ix0rDMh.png) periodically:**

[image]